# Sampling in cypher Query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm struggling with Cypher to perform a sampling over my user activity.

**What does my graph look like**

I have a few millions users recorder in my Graph with an indexed property UserId.

I have few hundreds Products with the indexed property ItemId.

My users can [INTERACTS] with my products.

**What I'm trying to do**

I would like to have an average idea over the path *user-[INTERACTS]-product-[INTERACTS]-user-[INTERACTS]-product* . In plain english I would like to know which products the look-alike user are interacting with. Eg if I interacts with products A and B, users interacting with these products generally interacts with these other products.

It's what Amazon do.

**My problem**

I can't simply match the above pattern, it takes way too long to execute. So I thought that I can only sample my user and that I could do the following :

- Take only the last 20 products my user interacts with
- Take only the last 20 users using each of the above products
- Take only the last 20 products these users interacted with, and counting each product occurrence

But I don't know if this is even possible in one single Cypher query.

The closest I came was the following query. But it still is too long, and it does not do what I want. Basically it gives me the latest products used by the "latest" user which has the "latest" products in common with the root user, which seems logic to me, but fails to sample my users' activity.

```
START u=node:node_auto_index('UserId:9554')  
MATCH 
    u-[i1:INTERACTS]-p1  
WITH 
    u,p1,i1 
LIMIT 20  
MATCH 
    p1-[i2:INTERACTS]-u1 
WHERE 
    NOT(u1=u) 
WITH 
    i1,i2,u1,p1 
LIMIT 400  
MATCH 
    u1-[i3:INTERACTS]-p 
WHERE 
    NOT(p1=p) AND p.ProjectId = {ProjectId} AND p.IsActive? = 1 
RETURN 
    i1.Label, i2.Label,i3.Label, p.ItemId,count(p) as count
LIMIT 8000
```

**Where am I now**

After some more unsuccessful testing I tried to code it using the Java API, and it is way more simpler and straight forward. But out of curiosity and because for now my system use Cypher I would like to know how to do this

For the sake of testing I think my question could be reduce to : Given a pattern, what is the last 2 node of each depth.

I created http://console.neo4j.org/?id=inf2hn in order to test it. I think the final result I'm looking for should look like :

```
Product 2 | User 3 | Product 5
Product 2 | User 3 | Product 6
Product 2 | User 4 | Product 5
Product 2 | User 4 | Product 6
Product 3 | User 3 | Product 5
Product 3 | User 3 | Product 6
Product 3 | User 4 | Product 5
Product 3 | User 4 | Product 6
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

I think what you mentioned in the comments reflects the fact that it may not just be a simple query. I've written recommendations using Neo4j and to me it looks like what you need it to account for all the various types of interactions with a product and how important they are. Based on that you form a ranked list of product interaction for a user i.e. products that the user is most "interested" in. 
To find products to recommend to another user, you can calculate how similar the user is to others, and then use those as the starting point for recommending products (if my tastes are similar to yours, I might be interested in the same products that you are).

Some blogs that might help:

http://blog.everymansoftware.com/2012/02/similarity-based-recommendation-engines.html

http://thought-bytes.blogspot.in/2012/02/similarity-based-recommendations-with.html

Disclaimer: I am the owner of the thought bytes blog.

Comment: That's interesting. I will look into this solution to see if it can solve my problems

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think you are trying to make some think like recommendations for the users..
If it exactly what you are looking for, i recently had built my own recommendation engine for users and products..

Say we have user A who BUY products 1,2,3 and user B who BUY 1,2,4.. so if want to recommend products for user A depending on similarities between A, B it will be product 4..

In cypher it looks like this:

```
Start inputUser=node:usersIndeinputUser(USER_NAME='A') 
MATCH (inputUser)-[rel1:BUY]->(common_products)<-[rel2:BUY]-(otherUser)-[rel3?:BUY]->(rec_product)  
With  rec_product,inputUser, otherUser
WHERE NOT (rec_product)<-[:BUY]-(inputUser)  
RETURN inputUser , rec_product, , otherUser
```

I wish it help you..

Comment: Recommendation is what I'm trying to achieve. But in my case it's not as simple as black/white, or has it/does not have it. Users can interact with a product in some different ways (preview, read, buy...), and each ways will weight differently. And I need to take all this ways into account. 

However I will keep your query in mind because it seems to be a lot faster than any query I ever made for this matter. It must be the WHERE clause which speed it.

Comment: This is the simple way to get recommendation, but it can be more complex by using more than relation type and ordering the result using some rates.. For example:




Start inputUser=node:usersIndeinputUser(USER_NAME='A') 
MATCH (inputUser)-[rel1:BUY|VIEW|SELL]->(common_products)<-[rel2:BUY|VIEW|SELL]-(otherUser)-[rel3?:BUY|VIEW|SELL]->(rec_product)  
With  rec_product,inputUser, otherUser, max(rel3.Rating) AS Rate
WHERE NOT (rec_product)<-[:BUY]-(inputUser)  
RETURN inputUser , rec_product, otherUser, Rate
ORDER BY  Rate

Comment: Yes indeed, but making a query is not my only problem. As I said in my introduction my graph has a lot of user and few products. So the pattern you are proposing won't finish in less than 15 minutes on my middle size database. I can put a limit in the query you are proposing, but in this case it behaves as I described : I will get all the product bought/viewed/sold by 1 user and not a sampling of users.

Comment: You want to limit what exactly, users or products seen by users??. The query only takes milliseconds and get the data as I expect.

Comment: Like I said I have million of users, each one doing tens or hundreds of actions on my products. So the following pattern parts yields too many results to be handled : _(other‌​User)-[rel3?:BUY|VIEW|SELL]->(rec_product)_ . And I can't do an ORDER BY, it is even worse. So using only LIMIT will order descending naturally by otherUsers and its products, so will only give me the products 1 user interacts with. Sorry for the poor explanation it's hard to put it into words

Comment: Sorry if I can't understand, but in my model I have roughly 10 million product and 2 million users who interact with these products in total of roughly 35 million relation. My goal is to get recommended products for a user, and order the result using the rates and the most common user with the input user. I limit the whole result and it works fine for me..